# Github Actions - How to pass generated folder to Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions, workflow, vite

I am trying to dockerize my large vite application. When running vite build inside of the Dockerfile, I get an out of memory error.

To fix this, I decided to run vite build inside of the Github action itself. Now I want to pass the the generated folder (dist) to my Dockerfile. The action is failing inside the docker file when trying to copy the dist folder in.

Here is my workflow

```
name: Build Image

on:
  push:
    branches: ["Kev-TestImage"]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: "npm"
      - run: npm install --legacy-peer-deps
      - run: npm run build
      - uses: azure/docker-login@v1
        with:
          login-server: hidden
          username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}

      - run: |
          docker build . -t hidden
          docker push hidden
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-bullseye-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps

# Copy the generated 'dist' folder into the container
COPY dist ./dist
COPY vite.config.ts ./vite.config.ts

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "preview"]
```

[image: Github Actions Error in logs]

Comment: Failing from what reason? Could you provide logs?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I updated the post with a screenshot of the error at the bottom

Comment: You should check where the `dist` folder is being created; maybe the path you mentioned does not point to the correct location.